# converting rows to column for a set of ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Consider the following query:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(
    CompanyId INT, 
    DirectorName VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @t1
   VALUES
      (1,'D11'),
      (1,'D12'),
      (1,'D13'),
      (1,'D14'),
      (1,'D15'),
      (1,'D16'),
      (2,'D21'),
      (2,'D22'),
      (2,'D23'),
      (2,'D24'),
      (2,'D25'),
      (2,'D26'),
      (2,'D27'),
      (2,'D28'),
      (2,'D29'),
      (2,'D210'),
      (3,'D31'),
      (3,'D32'),
      (3,'D33');

SELECT * FROM @t1
```

It simply returns the companyId and set of directors for that Id. How can I generate below output:

```
 CompanyId | Director1| Director2| Director3|Director4| Director5| Director6| Director7| Director8| Director9| Director10|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1           D11        D12       D13       D14        D15         D16       NULL        NULL       NULL      NULL
       2           D21        D22       D23       D24        D25         D26       D27         D28        D29       D210 
       3           D31        D32       D33       NULL       NULL        NULL      NULL        NULL       NULL      NULL
```

What makes above query trick is that the number of directors are different for each company. In above example row  number 2 has the highest number of directors which means the relevant columns for other ids inside final output those rows will be null. How can I create above output.

*Just to make it clear, the result will not go beyond 10 columns (directors) for each id (companyId) in this example.*

Comment: SQL queries return a fixed number of columns.  If you want a variable number of columns, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: In this particle problem I know for sure the result will not go beyond the max number of 10. So for sure I know what the max is.

Comment: @Gordon - Too many people are trying to pivot

Comment: What will be the logic to select top 10 directors?

Comment: the logic is distinct (DirectorName) for each Id meaning for every Id I would like to see the distinct director names  as column

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution using [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot):

```
SELECT CompanyId, [Director1], [Director2], [Director3], [Director4], [Director5], [Director6], [Director7], [Director8], [Director9], [Director10] 
FROM (
  SELECT CompanyId, DirectorName, 'Director' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId ORDER BY CompanyId, DirectorName) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS column_name 
  FROM @t1
) st PIVOT (
  MIN(DirectorName) 
  FOR column_name IN ([Director1], [Director2], [Director3], [Director4], [Director5], [Director6], [Director7], [Director8], [Director9], [Director10])
) pt
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fe1fa1cf8b9bc4c5e63e91d33d2bcf77)

Answer (score 1):

With the use of a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and Conditional aggregation you can do this

As long as the number of directors for each company doesnt exceed 10

```
;with cteGetDirectorNum
AS(
    select
         T.CompanyId
        ,T.DirectorName
        ,DirectorNum    ='Director'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Row_Number()over( partition by T.CompanyId order by T.CompanyId, T.DirectorName))
    from
        @t1     T
)
SELECT
     N.CompanyId
    ,Director1      = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director1' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
    ,Director2      = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director2' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
    ,Director3      = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director3' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
    ,Director4      = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director4' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
    ,Director5      = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director5' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
    ,Director6      = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director6' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
    ,Director7      = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director7' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
    ,Director8      = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director8' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
    ,Director9      = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director9' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
    ,Director10     = MAX(CASE WHEN N.DirectorNum = 'Director10' THEN n.DirectorName ELSE NULL END)
FROM
    cteGetDirectorNum N
GROUP BY N.CompanyId
```